# how get query with >= =< more filters

Tags: python, django

Have code

```
    shops = Shop.objects
    shops.filter(id__in=list(set(shop_ids)))
    if min:
        shops.filter(delivery_price >= min)
    if max:
        shops.filter(delivery_price =< max)
    shops.all()
```

but delivery_price is not defined.... how i can fix it?
and get queryset with more than 1 filter

```
class Shop(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Название')
time_begin = models.TimeField(max_length=255,
                              verbose_name=u'Время начала работы')
time_end = models.TimeField(max_length=255,
                            verbose_name=u'Время окончания работы')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Телефон')
preview = models.FileField(upload_to='files/shop/preview')
delivery_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Стоимость доставки')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django ORM you are not using comparison signs you are using field lookups

```
shops = Shop.objects
shops.filter(id__in=list(set(shop_ids)))
if min:
    shops.filter(delivery_price__gte=min)
if max:
    shops.filter(delivery_price__lte=max)
shops.all()
```

[Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

per @Sayse comment regarding your saving of queryset

```
shops = Shop.objects.filter(id__in=list(set(shop_ids)))
if min:
    shops = shops.filter(delivery_price__gte=min)
if max:
    shops = shops.filter(delivery_price__lte=max)
```

Also note out if you are using default manager you can ommit .all()

Comment: This still won't do alot since the filter is never assigned to anything

Comment: @Sayse yep didn't look into it further :)

Comment: True, your answer does solve the op's error, and I'm sure it won't be hard for the OP to solve that issue :)

Comment: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'delivery_price_lte' into field. Choices are: cook, cuisineshop, del_wait_time, delivery_price, desc_cook, description, destination, dishshop, email, foodtypemain, fslidershop, honorsshop, id, image_cook, is_always, is_card, is_cash, is_online, is_points, menushop, min_order, name, notification, phone, photoshop, preview, promocode, rate, reviewshop, shoptype, shoptype_id, slider, slider_id, specific, time_begin, time_end, userorder

Comment: @СергейПотапов - double underscore `__lte`

Comment: ty for your time!